# How to convert string into a function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable with a call to a function in string format. For example...

```
val = "add(3,4)"
```

and the function is

```
def add(a,b):
     sum =a+b;
     print(sum)
```

this is received from a file and therefore can't be changed. Is there a way I can convert the string into a format which I can call the function? i.e.

```
add(3,4)
```

which would run the `add(3,4)` function.

I tried to use `globals`:

```
s= globals()['add']
s()
```

but am unable to pass argument `add(3,4)`. Can any one help me how to pass arguments?

Comment: why can't you pass arguments `s(3, 4)`??

Comment: You could do something like this also ```python -c 'import file; print(file.add(3,4))'```

Comment: Wait, so your variable isn't the *name*of the function, but rather, an expression involving the function being called with some particular arguments? Why are you doing this? You should seriously reconsider the approach.

Comment: i can't separate arguments and functions

Comment: Why. Why are you doing this? In the end, you can use `eval` or `exec`, but you should seriously reconsider the entire approach

Comment: You need `eval`, or you need to parse the string yourself to extract the function name and its arguments. The former isn't safe unless you have complete control over the source of the variable, and the latter is probably more work than you really need to do. Why are you reading what amounts to an arbitrary expression from a file?

Answer (score 2):

In case the function arguments are made of literals you can use `ast.literal_eval` for parsing them:

```
import ast

func, args = val[:-1].split('(', 1)
globals()[func](*ast.literal_eval(args))
```

In order to have better control over what functions the user can trigger it's better to put them into a separate dictionary:

```
functions = {'add': add}
...
functions[func](*ast.literal_eval(args))
```

Otherwise any function from the global namespace could be (ab)used.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned utilizing [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval) is bad practice, and your design can probably use some adjustments.

However, you can add a bit of safety to your code if you perform a check before actually executing the `eval()` function:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a + b

func = "add(3,4)"

# Check if the calling function exists in `locals()` dictionary.
if func.split('(', maxsplit=1)[0] in locals():
    print(eval(func))   # Prints 7
```

Comment: This adds basically no safety at all. It only protects against a `NameError` from trying to call a function that doesn't exist; it doesn't protect against any of the actually dangerous things `eval` can do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval`.

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
eval('add(3,4)') # 7
```

Comment: Since the function name is stored in a variable `var` this would need to be `eval(f'{var}(3, 4)')` but this is **dangerous** since `var` can contain much more than just `"add"`.

Comment: @a_guest Apparently it's *not* just the name, but a full-blown call, that's read from a file.

Comment: yeah, i'm not sure exactly what the situation is, but I read it as reading the string 'add(3,4)' from a file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
val = 'add'

def add(value):
    return value

eval(val)(4)
```